# Making a Social Media app with Parse or developing my own backend?

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, social-networking, backend

Here is my dilemma, right now I am developing a social media app using Parse as my backend service and its working just fine. While doing some research today, I realized that if my app gains in popularity quickly using Parse will become very expensive or just stop requests all together that go over the limit.

1) Basically my question for you all is, in your experience with Parse how effective is it for handling apps with many users?

2) Also, do many users equate to many requests per second or is there an efficient way to develop my app that will keep the requests per second down?

3)And lastly would it just be easier/feasible to develop my own backend service for my app (I have no backend experience, so I would have to teach myself)? I am not opposed to doing this; I just know it will add development time but could be the best option in the long run.
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) We use Parse in our most of apps and Parse is handling things great. One of our app that uses Parse, has 3k monthly user and everything is going well

2) You should develop your app to make requests minimum. You must get lots of data as possible as you can. This will drop your request number.

3) I can recommend you that you should begin with Parse-like systems. We are in a time of hurry, so you must act lean. If Parse will not be enough for you in future, this is a thing that you must be happy about it. You can develop your own backend service meanwhile.

Comment: To add to Mert's second point, you'd be surprised just how much you could trim off your app's RPS just by asking yourself if there's a way to accomplish the same functionality persisting the data locally. Two suggestions from past experience: 1) Only save objects when changes were made locally (I.e., A request shouldn't be made if someone edits their name in your app but it's the same name that's currently saved to that object). 2) Pass around the actual object where applicable instead of passing the object's id and querying for it every new view controller.

Comment: Good points. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is good you are planning ahead parse or something similar like amazon is gonna be way better for scalability. If you get a domain and have a mysql database (or whatever else) that you maintain the scalability isn't as good as using a service that handles all of that.

I created my own backend and I wish I hadn't wasted the time.  I now will most likely have to find a service for scalability reasons so really just wasted my time making it.  That is just my two cents other people may disagree

Answer (score -1):

I think that building your own backend is very difficult and time consuming. Take a look at CloudKit, it gives you much better quotas than parse for free. Please note that you need an enrolled developer account to use it. Personally, I am making my app with Parse, and if I make it to be ready for release, I enroll into the programm and change the code to work with CloudKit, or leave it with Parse and if Parse quotas are nearly over, then I change to CloudKit. But Parse free quotas are quiet big as I experienced.